# Expected number of coin tosses to obtain first tail when probability of heads is $p$

Tags: probability

Suppose a coin is tossed independently and repeatedly with probability of heads equal to $p$.

What is the probability of only heads in the first $n$ tosses? $Try:$ I think since $ p$ is probability of heads, then the answer should be $p \cdot p \cdot ... \cdot p = p^n$ only heads in first $n$ tosses

What is the probability of obtaining the first tail at the $nth$ toss: I believe it should be $p^{n-1}(1-p) $ since $1-p$ is probability of tail.

I am stuck when I am asked to find the expected number of tosses required to obtain first tail. How can I answer this?

Comment: Your first two answers are right. For the last question, the distribution is geometric, the expected waiting time is $\frac{1}{1-p}$. Standard result. Has been on MSE several times, is also discussed in Wikipedia under geometric distribution, and many other places.

Comment: If $X$ is the number of flips till the first tail, then $E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^\infty i \cdot p(X=i)$.